# Who Survives the End of Times?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar

At the End of Times everybody

> died...

However Nagash, Sigmar and Arielle (doesn't she rule the Realm of Life?) all make appearances in the Age of Sigmar.

Originally I believed that all the incarnates survived (or were resurrected) and became guardians of their realms but now I recognize various Lizardman heroes.

Who survived the End of Times (or at least made it to the Age of Sigmar) and for a bonus point... how?

Comment: https://1d4chan.org/wiki/The_End_Times

Comment: Thanks for the spoiler...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Daft [provided the link](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/The_End_Times#Survivors) with all the information, so let me just paste it here (after de-4Channing it a bit)

- Sigmar- Grips onto the metal core of the world that was and becomes a true god in the new world. Creates the Stormcast Eternals as a force to oppose chaos.
- Tyrion- Diefied in the new world, He joins Sigmar in building the new civilizations. He goes against Sigmar's orders and leads his forces alongside Malerion's to capture Slaanesh.
- Teclis- Survived, and acts as Tyrion's guide while the latter is blind.
- Malekith- Comes back as a shadow creature fused with his dragon and calls himself Malerion; looks like Games Workshop backed down in the "whose Malekith came first?" spat with Marvel. What's also interesting, if Malekith fused with his dragon, and his dragon was female...
- Morathi- The bitch is back. Not only escaped Slaanesh, but appeared by herself in the Realm of Shadow with Daemonette servants until her son found her.
- Nagash- Surprise! the great necromancer survives, and joins Sigmar for a while. He gets pissed that now he's just one god in a huge pantheon, so he rebels and this leads to open war between the living and the dead.
- Alarielle- Survived and took some seeds from the Warhammer world and planted them in her life realm. Went into hiding and tried to get over her PTSD brought on by the End Times through gardening. Nurgle's got his eye on her, so that may change.
- Grimnir-the original, not Gotrek. He goes to fight some ancient dragon god, and both end up destroyed in the fight
- Grungi- Helps Sigmar forge the stormcast eternals.
- Gork & Mork - Now known as Gorkamorka, he joined Sigmar's alliance initially, but just wanted to fight and ended up leading the savage elements of the alliance away. Sometimes they're one being, sometimes they're two.
- The Skaven- One of only two races to maintain their identity from the old world, they are still allied with Chaos.
- Lizardmen- The other race to maintain their identity. Escaped on their temple-ships. Only the Warhammer world was destroyed, not the stars, that was just in the novel version.
- Kroak is back and even more powerful than before.
- Mannfred- Shown in the promotional art for WD leading the undead. In lore, he's now a charred, fanged walking skeleton, banished by Nagash to a place where everything keeps decaying but can't die as punishment for his role in the Warhammer World's destruction. SPOILER ALERT: Has a cameo in the audio book "Prisoner of the Black Sun" as the titular prisoner.
- Arkhan- shown alongside Nagash leading the undead against the warriors of Khorne. It's implied that he retrieved Nagash's body after he was killed by Archaon.
- Neferata- She's ruling a part of the realm of Shyish called Nulahmia. She's forced to defend it against chaos armies of Slaanesh but has to eventually get rescued by the Stormcast Eternals
- The Glottkin- Either Nurgle's giving them another chance or his keeping them in jars in his mansion was a way to protect them from the End Times.
- The Maggoth riders
- Archaon, now known as the Destroyer of Worlds, is once again the big bad during the reign of Chaos. All those rumors about him being the new hero are complete shit. One wonders why he still serves Chaos since the Warhammer world has been destroyed and Sigmar has been irrefutably proven to be real and a god. GW seems to have trouble with consistent writing. He even got to keep his steed Dorghar, although Dorghar has changed dramatically.
- Skarr Bloodwrath- Somehow brought back and serves the Khornate Bloodborn. Not bad for a new guy.
- Valkia the Bloody- Khorne really does care about her it seems.
- Scyla Anfingrimm- Surviving a fall of a high tower and an apocalypse confirms him as the most badass chaos spawn.
- Gotrek Gurnisson - the legendary Slayer is back as he emerges from the Realms of Chaos into the mortal world. Unfortunately, no signs of Felix yet.

Even bigger list can be found on lexicanum:

- [Characters](https://ageofsigmar.lexicanum.com/wiki/List_of_Characters)
- [Deities (including ascended mortals)](https://ageofsigmar.lexicanum.com/wiki/Deity#List)

Comment: Interesting read - do you know the orginal GW references for this?

Answer (score 3):

From the summary at [Lustria online](http://www.lustria-online.com/threads/the-full-tale-of-the-end-times-archaon.15921/) I got this information:

- Nagash attempts to overpower the forces of Chaos, but even with his monstrous willpower he eventually fails and goes roaring into the abyss and he disintegrates to dust.
- A falling boulder falls to crush Allarielle, but for reasons never expressed Malekith pushes her out of the way and his leg is crushed instead.  Not sure if she survives or gets consumed by the portal.
- Archaon hurls himself over the cliff edge as he climbed back up and slams into Sigmar. Both heavily wounded and exhausted, they battle over the Ghal Maraz and both of them go hurtling over the precipice into oblivion wrestling over the hammer - not sure if this means they survive or just keep falling into oblivion!

So according to the fluff, everyone kicks the bucket.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but some of those that died get better afterwards.